# how to permanently save changes into file in folder bundled while creating exe file using pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, exe, packaging

I have my exe application which i created with pyinstaller and bundled a folder while creating my exe which is working fine. In order to access any file from folder which i bundled while creating exe i can access those files from variable `sys._MEIPASS` since a temporary directory is created in `Temp/_MEI96522`

Now when i make a change into a file found in a folder it stays there while i am using a software but now when i close the software and open the software again the changes which i made in previous software session are gone. That file is now in its original form which it was before while bundling the folder containing the file in exe.

What i want to do is make a change into a file and needs to save the changes so that those changes stay there everytime i open the software after closing. 
Is there any way to do that while keeping the folder bundled with exe.

Comment: did you have any success achieving this ? Found a workaround or anything else ? I'm currently saving things in a `.json` file outside the bundled exe but if theres a way to wrap everything together that would really help.

Comment: No, the main problem I think is that the directory which is created is temporary and is deleted when the software is closed. So all the changes were temporary.

Comment: Thank you, I think I'll follow other solution like creating a specific folder for my application in `AppData` when the user launch the app for the first time.

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what I did.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this. In order for write file to work in pyinstaller --onefile exe, it needs an absolute path. therefore, we determine the location of the running executable so we can get the dir of your exe

```
import sys
import os

def get_executable_dir():
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):  # Check if the script is running as a standalone executable
        return os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    else:
        return os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

executable_dir = get_executable_dir()

with open(os.path.join(executable_dir, "config.txt"), "w") as f:
    f.write('config content')
```

This code will get the absolute path of your main .exe which lets you save a config file in that same dir.